# how to check whether selected dates contains from calendar contains date less than todays date

Tags: c#, wpf, date, calendar

I need to check if selected dates(multiple) from calendar control contains any single date which is already passed or less than today.
How is it possible in c# wpf application.

Comment: mvvm environment or simple environment ?

Comment: Can you show your code for how you are storing the selected dates from the calendar control?

Comment: I am selecting multiple dates from calendar at time in UI using mouse. so i need get all that dates and compare every single date with todays date.

Comment: I am using simple environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
SelectedDatesCollection selectedDatesCollection = myCalendar.SelectedDates;

if (selectedDatesCollection.Count > 0)
{
    if (selectedDatesCollection.Any(x => x < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)))
        MessageBox.Show("passed or less than today");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("today or future date");
}
```

Comment: Wow... Its awesome. short n simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateDynamicCalendar()  {  
Calendar MonthlyCalendar = new Calendar();  
MonthlyCalendar.Name = "MonthlyCalendar";  
MonthlyCalendar.Width = 300;  
MonthlyCalendar.Height = 400;  
MonthlyCalendar.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;  
MonthlyCalendar.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Month;  
MonthlyCalendar.SelectionMode = CalendarSelectionMode.MultipleRange;  
MonthlyCalendar.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2010, 3, 1);  
MonthlyCalendar.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2010, 3, 31);  
MonthlyCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(2010, 3, 5));  
MonthlyCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(2010, 3, 15));  
MonthlyCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(2010, 3, 25));  /*You Can Check all selected dates here with respect to current date*/

MonthlyCalendar.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;  
MonthlyCalendar.IsTodayHighlighted = true;  

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(MonthlyCalendar);  }
```

You can follow this link for WPF Calender Tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-calendar-control/